# How can I iterate over all possible values of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary where the value of each entry will either be a list or another dictionary whose entries are also lists. I want to create a python iterator that iterates over all possible states of the dictionary where the list at each key defines the possible values for that key.

I have tried iterating through each key and finding the next element in the list to use as the value but that only covers some of the combinations. This is because once a list is exhausted you need to reset to the first value and move to the next list.

If we give this dict to the iterator...

```
{
    "key0": {
        "key1": [1, 2],
        "key2": [8, 9, 10]
    }
    "key3": [22, 23, 24]
}
```

The first iteration it should produce is this...

```
{
    "key0": {
        "key1": 1,
        "key2": 8
    }
    "key3": 22
}
```

Then the second is this...

```
{
    "key0": {
        "key1": 2,
        "key2": 8
    }
    "key3": 22
}
```

Then the third is this...
(Notice how key1 goes back to 1)

```
{
    "key0": {
        "key1": 1,
        "key2": 9
    }
    "key3": 22
}
```

The expected result is to iterate over every possible state of the dictionary (18 total) where the list at each key defines the possible values for that key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a concise approach using `itertools.product` and recursion:

```
from itertools import product

def traverse(d):
    K,V = zip(*d.items())
    for v in product(*(v if isinstance(v,list) else traverse(v) for v in V)):
        yield dict(zip(K,v))
```

Sample run:

```
>>> d = {
>>>     "key0": {
>>>         "key1": [1, 2],
>>>         "key2": [8, 9, 10]
>>>     },
>>>     "key3": [22, 23, 24]
>>> }

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([*traverse(d)])
[{'key0': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 8}, 'key3': 22},
 {'key0': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 8}, 'key3': 23},
 {'key0': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 8}, 'key3': 24},
 {'key0': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 9}, 'key3': 22},
 {'key0': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 9}, 'key3': 23},
 {'key0': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 9}, 'key3': 24},
 {'key0': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 10}, 'key3': 22},
 {'key0': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 10}, 'key3': 23},
 {'key0': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 10}, 'key3': 24},
 {'key0': {'key1': 2, 'key2': 8}, 'key3': 22},
 {'key0': {'key1': 2, 'key2': 8}, 'key3': 23},
 {'key0': {'key1': 2, 'key2': 8}, 'key3': 24},
 {'key0': {'key1': 2, 'key2': 9}, 'key3': 22},
 {'key0': {'key1': 2, 'key2': 9}, 'key3': 23},
 {'key0': {'key1': 2, 'key2': 9}, 'key3': 24},
 {'key0': {'key1': 2, 'key2': 10}, 'key3': 22},
 {'key0': {'key1': 2, 'key2': 10}, 'key3': 23},
 {'key0': {'key1': 2, 'key2': 10}, 'key3': 24}]
```

Comment: Great answer. Now what if there were some dict entries that were ints rather than lists and would stay the same throughout all iterations? I get an error if I try that

Comment: `for v in product(*(v if isinstance(v,list) else traverse(v) if isinstance(v,dict) else [v] for v in V)):` try this in place of the current `for` statement, @ColmanKoivisto

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not ordered structures, you should not try to iterate over them. However, if you must do so, an approach could be:

```
my_dict = {"a":1 ,"b":2,"c":3}

for key in my_dict.keys():
    #print the key
    print(key)
    #print the value corresponding to the key
    print(my_dict[key])
```

Replace the prints with whatever function you want and you should be fine! If you have nested dictionaries or lists, keep in mind that the values are (in your case) the dictionaries or lists, from there, you can manipulate them in the loop in a similar fashion.

```
my_dict = {"a":{"a_1":1,"a_2":2} ,"b":{"b_1":1,"b_2":2},"c":{"b_1":1,"b_2":2}}

for key in my_dict.keys():
    #print the key
    print(key)
    #print the dictionary corresponding to the key
    print(my_dict[key])
    for new_key in my_dict[key].keys():
        #print the keys of the nested dictionaries
        print(new_key)
        #print the values of the nested dictionaries
        print(my_dict[key][new_key])
```

This should work

Comment: There is of course `OrderedDict`, but as of python 3.6, dictionaries maintain insertion order.

Comment: Thanks for the input, useful to know!

Comment: This doesn't answer my question for a few reasons. 1 because you gave me a function and not an iterator. 2 because it doesnt show me how to keep track of what values I've incremented. And 3 it only works for double nested dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```py
xdict = {
    "key0": {
        "key1": [1, 2],
        "key2": [8, 9, 10]
    },
    "key3": [22, 23, 24]
}

def iterate (key, index):
    if (type(key) == list):
        if (index >= len(key)):
            return (key[0])
        else:
            return (key[index])
    elif (type(key) == dict):
        result = {}
        for item in key:
            result[item] = iterate(key[item], index)
        return result
```

After executing the following tests I get the result you talked about

```py
>>> iterate(xdict, 0)
{'key0': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 8}, 'key3': 22}
>>> iterate(xdict, 1)
{'key0': {'key1': 2, 'key2': 9}, 'key3': 23}
>>> iterate(xdict, 2)
{'key0': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 10}, 'key3': 24}
```

Comment: I see what you're going for but this solution only produces 3 of the 18 possible combinations. I want all 18

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try(sorry, the order is not right yet):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import product
from copy import deepcopy


input_dicts = {'key0': {'key1': [1, 2], 'key2': [8, 9, 10]}, 'key3': [22, 23, 24]}
input_list_of_list = []
od = OrderedDict()

for k, v in input_dicts.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        input_list_of_list.append(v)
        od[k] = None
    elif isinstance(v, dict):
        od[k] = OrderedDict()
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            if isinstance(v1, list):
                input_list_of_list.append(v1)
                od[k][k1] = None

all_combinations = product(*input_list_of_list)
output = []
for c in all_combinations:
    l = len(c)
    s = 0
    for k, v in od.items():
        if not isinstance(v, dict):
            od[k] = c[s]
            s += 1
        else:
            for k1 in v:
                od[k][k1] = c[s]
                s += 1
    output.append(deepcopy(od))
```

output:

```
[
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 1), ("key2", 8)])), ("key3", 22)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 1), ("key2", 8)])), ("key3", 23)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 1), ("key2", 8)])), ("key3", 24)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 1), ("key2", 9)])), ("key3", 22)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 1), ("key2", 9)])), ("key3", 23)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 1), ("key2", 9)])), ("key3", 24)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 1), ("key2", 10)])), ("key3", 22)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 1), ("key2", 10)])), ("key3", 23)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 1), ("key2", 10)])), ("key3", 24)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 2), ("key2", 8)])), ("key3", 22)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 2), ("key2", 8)])), ("key3", 23)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 2), ("key2", 8)])), ("key3", 24)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 2), ("key2", 9)])), ("key3", 22)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 2), ("key2", 9)])), ("key3", 23)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 2), ("key2", 9)])), ("key3", 24)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 2), ("key2", 10)])), ("key3", 22)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 2), ("key2", 10)])), ("key3", 23)]),
    OrderedDict([("key0", OrderedDict([("key1", 2), ("key2", 10)])), ("key3", 24)]),
]
```